# Only convert images of a certain file type with paperclip styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, paperclip

I want to convert uploaded images that are not jpegs or pngs to to be jpegs or pngs using paperclip.  Problem is i dont want to convert jpegs to pngs or pngs to jpegs, just leave them as the file type they are.

Is this possible ? If so how do i create the styles all in jpeg or png ?

Also what is the best file type to save as?  I cant convert some pngs to jpgs as if they had transparency in that gets lost / changed.  Also if i change all to png is not bigger and alos i am using Prawn pdf outputting these images so cant use gif.

Any pointers anyone ?

Thanks alot
Rick

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will need to create a custom `Paperclip::Processor`. You can probably subclass the `Paperclip::Thumbnail` in doing so.